# All binary combinations in a 2d Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, permutation

I am trying to create a code that could generate all possible combinations of 0 and 1 in a numpy matrix excluding rotations.
What do I mean rotation? I mean that below matrix data are in fact the same because it has the same data but rotated 90º, 180º and 270º.

[image]

I have been trying below code but I think i am not getting all combinations and I have some of them missing. Do you have any idea if this is the right way? Do you know if there is any more efficient way?

For example, considering dx=3 and dy=3

```
import numpy as np

def myfunction(data)
   print(data)

dx=3
dy=3
data = np.zeros([dx, dy], dtype=np.uint8)

y=0

for x in range(dx):
    for r in range(2):
        data[x, y] = r
        myfunction(data)
        for y in range(dy):
            for s in range(2):
                data[x, y] = s
                myfunction(data)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is *myfunction* in the example code? What does *dx* and *dy* mean? `1 0 1` (90° rotation includes `0 1 0`) is missing, IIUC.

Comment: dx and dy is the size of the matrix. dx=2 and dy=2 would be a 2x2 matrix. myfunction is another function i need to call in each unique value.

Comment: Please clarify why the matrix should be 3x3 or 2x2 and provide a [mre]. For combinations of 3 elements the matrix is at least 4x3, but then 90° rotations are not possible.

Comment: hi, I just modified the title and the code can now be executed. I always mean a square matrix.

Comment: If you mean only square matrices, then I don’t see why are you defining both `dx` and `dy`. Also not sure what `myfunction` does, I mean you could use `print` itself and it also takes less time to write too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution that can work for small matrix sizes; comments in the code illustrate a 3 by 3 case:

```
def get_binary_mats(n):
  # all possible n by n binary matrices up to rotation: 
  bin_mats = (np.bitwise_and(np.arange(2**(n*n))[:,None], 2 ** np.arange(n*n)) > 0)\
    .reshape(-1, n, n)
  # define a score for each matrix based on position of ones
  score = 2 ** np.arange(n*n).reshape(n,n)
  # array([[  1,   2,   4],
        #  [  8,  16,  32],
        #  [ 64, 128, 256]])
  score_arr = np.stack([np.rot90(score, k=k) for k in range(4)])
  # array([[[  1,   2,   4],
  #         [  8,  16,  32],
  #         [ 64, 128, 256]],

  #        [[  4,  32, 256],
  #         [  2,  16, 128],
  #         [  1,   8,  64]],

  #        [[256, 128,  64],
  #         [ 32,  16,   8],
  #         [  4,   2,   1]],

  #        [[ 64,   8,   1],
  #         [128,  16,   2],
  #         [256,  32,   4]]])

  scores = np.einsum("ijk,ljk->il", bin_mats, score_arr)
  _, idx = np.unique(scores.min(1), return_index=True)
  return bin_mats[idx,...]
```

The main idea is that we can take a "dot product" of an N by N binary matrix with an N by N matrix consisting of first N^2 powers of 2 (I call the latter the score matrix). When we do this, we get a unique integer for each possible binary matrix.

To account for rotations, we can take a "dot product" with 4 rotations of the "score" matrix, and associate each binary matrix to the minimum of the four results. We can refer to this minimum as a score of a binary matrix.

Finally, we can pick a matrix for each unique score with `np.unique`. For example, here is the output for n = 2:

```
array([[[False, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[ True, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[ True,  True],
        [False, False]],

       [[False,  True],
        [ True, False]],

       [[ True,  True],
        [ True, False]],

       [[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]]])
```

As a sanity check, the number of binary matrices up to rotation lines up with [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A047937) for n up to 5:

```
%time assert [get_binary_mats(k).shape[0] for k in range(1, 6)] == [2, 6, 140, 16456, 8390720]
# takes 20 seconds on my machine
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much! That is exactly what I am looking for! The only issue is that for values more than 5 it is imposible due the high memory needed to store all the combinations needed in beforehand. Do you see a way in which a function could be executed in each iteration without generate all the values at once?

Comment: I am also thinking that another option could be to split the calculus in different arrays, but i dont see the way.

Comment: It might be touch to process matrices of size greater than 5 regardless, as their number grows pretty quickly. If memory is a constraint but you have the processing power, you can try to generate random matrices in batches based on the number of ones.

Comment: Hello Hilberts, i posted this question mainly to try to extend your code to not only binary values. Any help from your side would be really helpful. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72293279/all-combinations-in-a-2d-numpy

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my answer is most efficient way, but anyways.

We can rotate each matrix using `numpy.rot90` function.

Lets Create two different dictionaries, one to store the main matrices, the other one to store main matrices' rotations, so we can verify if a new matrix is just a rotation of previously found matrices.

```
def Not_Rotated(dx, dy):
    import numpy as np
    from itertools import product

    Big_Matrix = np.array([[list(i[x:x+dx]) for x in range(0, len(i), dx)] for i in product("01", repeat=dx*dy)])  # Stores all possible combinations

    Main = dict()  # Stores not rotated
    Main_c = 0

    Rotations = dict()  # Stores rotated
    Rotation_c = 0

    for i in range(len(Big_Matrix)):  # Going through all combinations
        flag = 1  # A flag to check if this combination is rotated of previous ones or not. 1= is not rotated of previous ones. 0 = is rotated.
        for z in range(Rotation_c):
            if np.array_equal(Big_Matrix[i],Rotations[z]):  # Checking if this combination is rotated of previous ones or not
                flag = 0

        if flag:  # If this combination is not a rotation of previous ones
            Main[Main_c] = Big_Matrix[i]
            # Rotate it three times and store the matrices
            Rotations[Rotation_c] = np.rot90(Main[Main_c])
            Rotations[Rotation_c + 1] = np.rot90(Main[Main_c])
            Rotations[Rotation_c + 2] = np.rot90(Main[Main_c])
            Rotation_c += 3
            Main_c += 1
    return Main
```