# All combinations in a 2d Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, combinations, permutation

I am trying to modify the code provided as answer by Hilberts in below question to allow it for multiple values and not only binary.
[All binary combinations in a 2d Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654582/all-binary-combinations-in-a-2d-numpy)

So, rather than only allow 0 and 1 like in the previous example, i would like find all combinations without rotations for data like 0, 1, 2 and 3 .

I modified it in this way, mainly replacing the "2" in the original code by a variable and tried to replace it by the variable "m" to follow the initial formula. But I think the issue here is related to the numpy type of data "bitwise_and" . Does anyone have any advices about what would be problem or any hint?

```
  def get_binary_mats(n,m):
  # all possible n by n binary matrices up to rotation: 
  bin_mats = (np.bitwise_and(np.arange(m**(n*n))[:,None], m ** np.arange(n*n)) > 0)\
    .reshape(-1, n, n)
  # define a score for each matrix based on position of ones
  score = m ** np.arange(n*n).reshape(n,n)
  # array([[  1,   2,   4],
        #  [  8,  16,  32],
        #  [ 64, 128, 256]])
  score_arr = np.stack([np.rot90(score, k=k) for k in range(4)])
  # array([[[  1,   2,   4],
  #         [  8,  16,  32],
  #         [ 64, 128, 256]],

  #        [[  4,  32, 256],
  #         [  2,  16, 128],
  #         [  1,   8,  64]],

  #        [[256, 128,  64],
  #         [ 32,  16,   8],
  #         [  4,   2,   1]],

  #        [[ 64,   8,   1],
  #         [128,  16,   2],
  #         [256,  32,   4]]])

  scores = np.einsum("ijk,ljk->il", bin_mats, score_arr)
  _, idx = np.unique(scores.min(1), return_index=True)
  return bin_mats[idx,...]
```

Thank you

Comment: When you say you want `0,1,2,3` What should be your output? can you give the head of your output?

Comment: As an output i would have all the combinations of a matrix in which 0, 1, 2, 3 are involved.
I mean all values from
[[0 0]
[0 0]] to [[3 3][3 3]]

Comment: Why are you putting them in a list of 2?

Comment: Also how many numbers in total? 256?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as combn
list(combn([0,1,2,3], 4))

[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 0, 3),
 (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 2),
 (0, 0, 1, 3),
 (0, 0, 2, 2),
 (0, 0, 2, 3),
 (0, 0, 3, 3),
 (0, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 1, 3),
 (0, 1, 2, 2),
 (0, 1, 2, 3),
 (0, 1, 3, 3),
 (0, 2, 2, 2),
 (0, 2, 2, 3),
 (0, 2, 3, 3),
 (0, 3, 3, 3),
 (1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 1, 3),
 (1, 1, 2, 2),
 (1, 1, 2, 3),
 (1, 1, 3, 3),
 (1, 2, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 3),
 (1, 3, 3, 3),
 (2, 2, 2, 2),
 (2, 2, 2, 3),
 (2, 2, 3, 3),
 (2, 3, 3, 3),
 (3, 3, 3, 3)]
```